# Sub menu gets buried by next menu structure

Tags: css, menu

I have a website with two nav bars, one is a header menu and is offset to the right and the other is the top nav bar which takes you to all the pages. My problem is that the header menu's sub menu, when extended, goes under the top nav bar menu, so you're unable to see the sub menu. I want it to go on top of the top nav bar so people can click on the links. As you can see in screen shot, to the far right, the top menu is buried under the next nav bar.

[image: Screenshot of nav menus]

Any help would be appreciated.
Heidi

```
<div class="half">
    <ul id="menu-header-menu" class="header menu">
        <li id="menu-item-77" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-25 current_page_item menu-item-77"><a href="https://test-link.com/" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-79" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-79"><a href="https://test-link2.com/">About</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-17950" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-17950"><a href="https://test-link3.com/">Blog</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-80" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-80"><a>Contact</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-343" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-343"><a href="https://test-link-child1/">Bio</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-344" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-344"><a href="https://test-link-child2/">Contact Jeri</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The css is as follows:

```
.header.menu {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    z-index: 50;
    float: right;
}
.menu ul {
    width: 200px;
}
#menu-header-menu ul.sub-menu {
     background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Comment: The **container** of the top nav bar needs to have a higher z-index than the **container** of the next nav menu. (The menu can't have a higher z-index than its container.) I can't be too specific, as your code doesn't show the situation clearly, but it may mean giving `.half` something like `position: relative; z-index: 2`.